I cannot control the token added with Next.js JWT
export const getDataFromToken = (request: NextRequest) => {
    try {
        const token = request.cookies.get("token")?.value || '';
        const decodedToken:any = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET!);
        return decodedToken.id;
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }

}

This is my getDataFromToken.ts file.
export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await axios.get('/api/users/logout')
        toast.success('Logout success')
        router.push('/giris')
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.log(error.message);
        toast.error(error.message)
    }
}


useEffect(() => {
  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    try {
      const token = getDataFromToken(); 
      setIsLoggedIn(!!token);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };
  checkLoggedIn();
}, []);


const login = () => {
  router.push('/giris');
}

return (
  <>
    <main className="flex mt-3">
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <button onClick={logout} className="ms-auto me-4">
          {'Çıkış Yap'}
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={login} className="ms-auto me-4">
          {'Giriş Yap'}
        </button>
      )}
      <span>  </span>
    </main>
  </>
);
}

This is my homepage.
What I want to do is this; If there is a token registered on the site, it will say 'Log out'. If there is no token, it means the user has logged out or never logged in. That's why it will say 'Sign in' there too. But here's the problem. Since I have assigned a request to getDataFromToken, I cannot call it directly. me where I use getDataFromToken
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
Gives a fault. Because I didn't add anything in getDataFromToken() in my main page. I didn't understand how to control this.
Since I have assigned a request to getDataFromToken, I cannot call it directly.
